# How to run c programm via sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, c

I want to run two c programs in the home directory, but the programs are stored in another directories, where each has own directory. So, I do followings:

I have two scripts for each program in their directories:

Script run_rd.sh with the content:

```
     #!/bin/bash
     sudo ./recv_csi tst.dat
```

Script run_sd.sh with the content:

```
     #!/bin/bash
     sudo ./send_Data wlan4 00:01:02:03:04:05 10
```

I have another script in the home directory, which calls the scripts from above. The goal is to run both c programs at the same time:

Script run.sh with the content:

```
     #!/bin/bash
     pathToRecvCSI="/home/ubuntu/A-Tool-APP/recvCSI/"
     pathToSendData="/home/ubuntu/A-Tool-APP/sendData/"


     sh $pathToRecvCSI"run_rd.sh" &  PIDIOS=$!
     sh $pathToSendData"run_sd.sh" &  PIDMIX=$!
     wait $PIDIOS
     wait $PIDMIX
```

After execution I get the following output:

```
  sudo: ./send_Data: command not found
  sudo: ./recv_csi: command not found
```

But, if I will execute run_sd.sh/run_rd.sh separately in their directories, they run as normal.

What is the reason why the run.sh prints that output?
Could someone help me?

PS: All scripts has executable permissions.

Comment: Because `./` means the current directory - you either need to change to the respective directory first, or use an absolute path. Also, don't use `sh` (`dash`) to run `bash` scripts.

Comment: Try cd $pathToRecvCSI && ./run_rd.sh